# Android how to store my jpeg file in Mobile internal Storage. It doesn't have an SD CARD

Tags: android, file, mobile, storage

I want to save a picture file from Internet to my mobile. I have used both Internet and externalstorage Permission in AndroidManifest file. But it gives an error given below. I think it is because my device don't have an SD CARD. If so then I want to know how to store in Internal storage.

**myError**

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/GettyImages-460712009-560x450.jpg: open
>   failed: EACCES (Permission denied Caused by:
>   android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

**Below is my code.**

```
try {
        URL urlobj = new URL(url);
        connection= (HttpURLConnection) urlobj.openConnection();
        inputStream=connection.getInputStream();

           file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + "/"+ Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment());

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            int reed = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            // if no data is return -1 keep reading until -1
            while( ( reed=inputStream.read(buffer) )!= -1){

            fileOutputStream.write(buffer,0,reed);               
}
```

Comment: post your permissions. and if using marshmallow you have to allow permission from your app info

Comment: On which device you run? if its marshmallow please change it to lollipop or below marshmallow. if this is not possible please give permission from setting in your app permission allow

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Permission denied Exception because you are not implementing Run Time permission for Devices having Android Marshmallow and above version  ..

This is how you can achieve this :

Add following permission to manifest like earlier :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Match if the user has already granted the permission. If yes, skip asking for permission and continue with your work else ask user for permission :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2909);
        } else {
            // your code
        }
    } else {
        // your code
    }
```

Permission result callback:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 2909: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.e("Permission", "Granted");
                } else {
                    Log.e("Permission", "Denied");
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! My device was on marshmallow.

Comment: Thanks! My device was on marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

To save an image in internal memory use this code.

You should add permission in you manifast file`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

You need run time permission in marshmallow and above version, for that use [Amit sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42529878/3615605) Answer.

Here is the code to save a file in Default picture directory.

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

For mode details please check this [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)